# Would like to stop execution of code when a match is met

Tags: arrays, angularjs, loops, foreach

I created this service method in Angular JS which checks if an array of potential statuses(pendingApplications) match any of an array of set statuses(applicableStatuses). For this to work it meetsStatusCondition should return true after the first match occurs. Only 1 of the numbers in pendingApplications array needs to match and I'd like to end the execution of this function. Currently it's looping through every item in pendingApplications array

```
    `containsApplicableStatus: function(pendingApplications, applicableStatuses) {
        pendingApplications.forEach(function(status) {
            if (applicableStatuses.includes(status)) {
                return pendingApplications.meetsStatusCondition = true;
            }
        });
    }`
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint on if (applicableStatuses.includes(status)) { to verify the expression is true? Additionally, I'd recommend make the return line into 2 lines.  pendingApplications.meetsStatusCondition = true; return;

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation with `.forEach`, you can't break out if it like you can with a for loop

Just a regular for loop will work

```
for (const status of applicableStatuses){
if (applicableStatuses.includes(status)) { 
pendingApplications.meetsStatusCondition = true; 
break //or return if you want to exit out of the enclosing function instead of just the loop
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Often when you want to short-circuit a `forEach` like this, what you're really looking for is another method like `find()` or `some()`.

```
containsApplicableStatus: function(pendingApplications, applicableStatuses) {
    pendingApplications.meetsStatusCondition = pendingApplications.some(function(status) {
        return applicableStatuses.includes(status)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in using `forEach` (which doesn't have a breaking option) if you could just use a regular `for ... of` loop instead:

```js
containsApplicableStatus: function(pendingApplications, applicableStatuses) {
  for (const status of pendingApplications) {
    if (applicableStatuses.includes(status)) {
      pendingApplications.meetsStatusCondition = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

However, even this seems a bit too complicated, you could just set `meetsStatusCondition` to the result of `some`:

```js
containsApplicableStatus: function(pendingApplications, applicableStatuses) {
  pendingApplications.meetsStatusCondition =
    pendingApplications.some(status => applicableStatues.includes(status));
}
```

I do wonder if it makes sense to set a non-index property on your array though, maybe rethink that. This works but it's usually not something you'd expect on an array, and it will be lost if you convert that array to JSON for instance.